# The dataframe index values are being used for x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a plot for a large data set of around 50,000 rows, where I am trying to plot a series for a single column of the data, but instead of using the unique row data values, it is using the index values ranging from 0 - 50,000 as x values. Is there any way I can somehow swap the x and y axis values?

The data being used is the PUMS household languages data

Here is a screenshot of the code and output of the plot in question:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCuiQ.png)

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). **Always** provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance, as no one wants to retype data/code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Plots are okay. See [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246)

Comment: What do you expect to happen with a line plot? You probably need a bar plot of the value_counts. `langData.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 0):

You want to plot the actual values of series on x-axis, not its index. So here is the simple code to do so:

```py
name = langData.name  # save the name of the column/series
langData = langData.reset_index()  # convert series to dataframe
langData = langData.set_index(name)  # set the values as series index
langData.plot()
```